# Defining a heirarchy for native code via ABIs

Tags: gradle, android-ndk

Please forgive my poor terminology, I'm not very familiar with the NDK.

I use two libraries. One generates native *.so libaries for armeabi, the other for armeabi-v7a. I would like to define a hierarchy to use the arm v7a libraries first, then basic arm second. At the moment, I'm using:

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
    }
```

To define the chipsets that I have libraries for, but that will only pull in the specific chipset of the decide. I.E., if the device is armeabi-v7a, the "armeabi-v7a" *.so libraries will be pulled in, and not "armeabi". If I remove "armeabi-v7a" from the config, "armeabi" will be pulled in.

Is there a way to define a hierarchy inside the app's build.gradle using flavours, or some other mechanism? [This seems possible using Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#am), but that seems more appropriate for if I was generating these *.so files myself, which I'm not. I'm just trying to use *.so files included in .jar(s) or .aar(s) that I'm including in my project.

Answer (score 0):

For a fat APK (where you have multiple ABIs worth of libraries in one APK), Android's package manager will handle selecting the right libraries for the device you're running on.

For a split APK (with one APK per ABI), the play store is responsible for installing the correct one: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits